# How to make DBconnection and Node.js Query file separately

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, json, node.js

I have question. How to connect dbconnection.js and demo_api_select.js I have a problem when declare variable on demo_api_select.js. It doesn't work and have error notification like this:

[Error Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLyWd.png)

Please help

> dbconnection.js:

```
var mysql=require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "test"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});


module.exports = con;
```

> demo_api_select.js

```
var db = require('./dbconnection');

db.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  //Select all customers and return the result object:
  con.query("SELECT * FROM profil" , function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

I want to make those code work as well as this code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "test"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  //Select all customers and return the result object:
  con.query("SELECT * FROM profil" , function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.No need to connect twice to database

```
var db = require('./dbconnection');

db.query("SELECT * FROM profil" , function (err, result, fields) {
   if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
   });
});
```

Comment: Wow It's Works Thank You